# Webapp routing with nginx

Tags: nginx

I try to serve a webapp with nginx, and everything goes fine while I request root url, like http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8002/ (I don't have a domain name, so IP address and port are used)

The app has it's own internal routing and I'd like to be able to use it from browser's address bar, like http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8002/profile.

I get 404, since nginx looks for directories in root folder, I guess.

I changed my config to look like this:

```
server {
    listen 8002 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root /home/ubuntu/sites/mysite-frontend;

    location ~ /.* {
        rewrite "/.*" / last;
    }
}
```

and now I get status code 500, and log shows the following:

2016/09/08 08:36:27 [error] 29869#0: *3 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/", client: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy, server: _, request: "GET /profile HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8002"

How should I change my config in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your webapp `/index.html`. The default value for the [`index` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) is `index.html`, which is why the default configuration works with the `/` URI.

You should add a [`try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) with the a default action of `/index.html`, in which case all URIs which point to a non-existent static file will be routed to your webapp.

```
server {
    listen 8002 default_server;
    index index.html;
    root /home/ubuntu/sites/mysite-frontend;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I have made the `index` directive explicit (but it is not necessary in this case).